# How to setup test Environment for javascript in Maven(Java)Project?

Tags: javascript, java, maven, jestjs, karma-jasmine

Am trying to setup test Environment for javascript in Maven project(Legacy project).Project Consist of Java with few Javascript files. Most of the javascript Changes am trying to write test case is related to UI changes.

Test case am trying to cover is

```
      $(document).ready(function() {
           $(document).keyup(onKeyUpHandler);
      });

      function onKeyUpHandler(e){
          if (e.key === "Escape")
              toggleDetailListing();
      }
      function toggleDetailListing() {
          if ($('#detail_listing').css('display') == 'block')
              $('#detail_listing').hide();
      }
```

How to write and setup test environment based on above Requirement ?